# Fetch imap body message by telnet

Tags: shell, email, imap, telnet

I know that to get all message body, this is the command:

```
[imap_code] UID FETCH [uid] BODY.PEEK[TEXT]
```

Thus I get the entire message body.
But I need to exclude the part of the attachments. I want only message wrote from sender, text and/or html.

Is there a way?

This is a full raw html mail with attachment

http://pastebin.com/FMEQdLM3

I would like to get only

```
<div dir="ltr">This is the message body<div><ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul></div></div>
```

or plain text if there isn't html version

Comment: Please update the question with a sample entry from the actual log and the actual output you are expecting

Comment: Ok, I have provided an example

Comment: Do all of your messages look like this example?

Answer (score 16):

Messages are laid out in an arbitrary tree of parts, with parent items being of the multipart/* or message/rfc822 type, and children being of other types.  The `FETCH BODY[...]` lets arbitrarily extract any of these parts.

Unfortunately, there is no standard layout for messages.  You can fetch the BODYSTRUCTURE item to get the MIME layout of a message, but it is very difficult to parse by eye.

That being said, there's a few common message layouts that will get you most of the way.

The easiest is a message with just one body, either text/html or text/plain.  Just fetch `BODY[TEXT]`.

The next is multi-format, with both text/html and text/plain.  Its MIME structure generally looks like this:

```
+ multipart/alternative   [TEXT]
|- text/plain             [1]
\- text/html              [2]
```

In this case you want to fetch `BODY[2]`.

If the message is single-body, with attachments, it will look something like this:

```
+ multipart/mixed or multipart/related  [TEXT]
|- text/html or text/plain              [1]
|- image/jpg                            [2]
| ...
\- image/gif
```

In this case you want `BODY[1]`.

Last is both of these: multi-format body with attachments.  It will tend to look something like:

```
+ multipart/mixed or multipart/related  [TEXT]
|-+ multipart/alternative               [1]
| |- text/plain                         [1.1]
| \- text/html                          [1.2]
|- image/jpeg                           [2]
|- image/gif                            [3]
|...
\- image/png
```

In this case, you probably want `BODY[1.2]`.  Your sample message is of this type.

---

In addition, the bodies may be encoded in Quoted-Printable or Base64 encoding.  Unfortunately, Baseline IMAP does not provide any way for the server to decode this for you.  Quoted-Printable can be mostly read if the message is ascii, but will have lots of `=` escapes throughout the body.  If it's base64, you're not going to be able to decipher it by eye.  The [BINARY IMAP extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3516) can help with this, but this is not widely deployed.

Comment: [Excuse my ascii art trees]

Comment: Does anybody understand just how great this answer is? Well, try finding this kind of detail in ANY RFC... OP, accept this immediately and buy this man a coffee.