# imap_fetchbody return strange string

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I'm having some problems with getting the message body from an email. I've searched for solutions but have still not found the solution. Below is the code

```
$imap_conn = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX','user','password');
$inbox = imap_search($imap_conn, 'ALL');

if (! empty($inbox)) {
    foreach($inbox as $email_number) {

        $message = imap_fetchbody($imap_conn,415,1.1);
        var_dump($message);
    }
```

The problem is that the $message variable comes with a strange big string value instead of coming with the message value. I would like to have the body part of the email that we write when sending an email.

This is the value i get: RXN0ZSBldmVudG8gZm9pIGFsdGVyYWRvLg0KDQpUw610dWxvOiBSZXVuacOjbyBUw6ljbmljYSBP
bnMzDQpRdWFuZG86IHF1aS4gMzAgU2V0LiAycG0g4oCTIHNleC4gMSBPdXQuIDIwMjEgN3BtIEhv
cmEgZGEgRXVyb3BhIE9jaWRlbnRhbCAtICANCkxpc2JvYSAoYWx0ZXJhZG8pDQpDYWxlbmTDoXJp
bzogbWFyY28uc2lsdmFAb25zZWFyY2

Comment: Why `1.1`? Have you ever bother to read the manual?

Comment: Maybe i'am a bit noob at this but i've tried them all. 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2

Comment: Bodies can be encoded in 7bit, 8bit, Quoted-Printable, or Base64.  This is base64.

Comment: Re: 1.1: the body can be in a lot of different places depending on who or what wrote the email.  It is not sufficient to use a static part number.  Emails can be assembled arbitrarily; this is kind of like saying “the kitchen is the first room on the left” for all houses you might walk into.  You need to get a map of the email (bodystructure) before you know which part to get.  Unless you’re always sure the email sender always uses the same format.

Comment: My answer here may help you understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787767/fetch-imap-body-message-by-telnet/37794152#37794152

Comment: Also if you check the part's headers it should tell you how it's encoded so that you can properly decode it.